# Making custom containers work with **kwargs (how does Python expand the args?)

Tags: python

I have a custom container class in Python 2.7, and everything works as expected *except* if I pass try to expand an instance as `**kwargs` for a function:

```
cm = ChainableMap({'a': 1})
cm['b'] = 2
assert cm == {'a': 1, 'b': 2} # Is fine
def check_kwargs(**kwargs):
   assert kwargs == {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
check_kwargs(**cm) # Raises AssertionError
```

I've overridden `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `iterkeys`, `keys`, `items`, and `iteritems`, (and `__eq__` and `__repr__`) yet none of them seem to be involved in the expansion as `**kwargs`, what am I doing wrong?

Edit - The working updated source that now inherits from MutableMapping and adds the missing methods:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import MutableMapping

class ChainableMap(MutableMapping):
    """
    A mapping object with a delegation chain similar to JS object prototypes::

        >>> parent = {'a': 1}
        >>> child = ChainableMap(parent)
        >>> child.parent is parent
        True

    Failed lookups delegate up the chain to self.parent::

        >>> 'a' in child
        True
        >>> child['a']
        1

    But modifications will only affect the child::

        >>> child['b'] = 2
        >>> child.keys()
        ['a', 'b']
        >>> parent.keys()
        ['a']
        >>> child['a'] = 10
        >>> parent['a']
        1

    Changes in the parent are also reflected in the child::

        >>> parent['c'] = 3
        >>> sorted(child.keys())
        ['a', 'b', 'c']
        >>> expect = {'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
        >>> assert child == expect, "%s != %s" % (child, expect)

    Unless the child is already masking out a certain key::

        >>> del parent['a']
        >>> parent.keys()
        ['c']
        >>> assert child == expect, "%s != %s" % (child, expect)

    However, this doesn't work::

        >>> def print_sorted(**kwargs):
        ...     for k in sorted(kwargs.keys()):
        ...         print "%r=%r" % (k, kwargs[k])
        >>> child['c'] == 3
        True
        >>> print_sorted(**child)
        'a'=10
        'b'=2
        'c'=3

    """
    __slots__ = ('_', 'parent')

    def __init__(self, parent, **data):
        self.parent = parent
        self._ = data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._[key]
        except KeyError:
            return self.parent[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterkeys()

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self._[key] = val

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.keys())

    def keys(self, own=False):
        return list(self.iterkeys(own))

    def items(self, own=False):
        return list(self.iteritems(own))

    def iterkeys(self, own=False):
        if own:
            for k in self._.iterkeys():
                yield k
            return
        yielded = set([])
        for k in chain(self.parent.iterkeys(), self._.iterkeys()):
            if k in yielded:
                continue
            yield k
            yielded.add(k)

    def iteritems(self, own=False):
        for k in self.iterkeys(own):
            yield k, self[k]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return sorted(self.iteritems()) == sorted(other.iteritems())

    def __repr__(self):
        return dict(self.iteritems()).__repr__()

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._ or key in self.parent

    def containing(self, key):
        """
        Return the ancestor that directly contains ``key``

        >>> p2 = {'a', 2}
        >>> p1 = ChainableMap(p2)
        >>> c = ChainableMap(p1)
        >>> c.containing('a') is p2
        True
        """
        if key in self._:
            return self
        elif hasattr(self.parent, 'containing'):
            return self.parent.containing(key)
        elif key in self.parent:
            return self.parent

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        """
        >>> c = ChainableMap({'a': 1})
        >>> c.get('a')
        1
        >>> c.get('b', 'default')
        'default'
        """
        if key in self:
            return self[key]
        else:
            return default

    def pushdown(self, top):
        """
        Pushes a new mapping onto the top of the delegation chain:

        >>> parent = {'a': 10}
        >>> child = ChainableMap(parent)
        >>> top = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'beer', 'c': 'cheese'}
        >>> child.pushdown(top)
        >>> assert child == top

        This creates a new ChainableMap with the contents of ``child`` and makes it
        the new parent (the old parent becomes the grandparent):

        >>> child.parent.parent is parent
        True
        >>> del child['a']
        >>> child['a'] == 10
        True
        """
        old = ChainableMap(self.parent)
        for k, v in self.items(True):
            old[k] = v
            del self[k]
        self.parent = old
        for k, v in top.iteritems():
            self[k] = v
```

Comment: Try stepping through with a debugger (or writing `print` statements in every overloaded function) to see which function is being called upon argument expansion.

Comment: Note that even if this were to work, `check_args` would get a *new* dictionary, not your subclass. See [the function definitions documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions); specifically *" If the form “**identifier” is present, it is initialized to a new dictionary receiving any excess keyword arguments, defaulting to a new empty dictionary."*.

Comment: @Lanaru putting an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` immediately before the call to `check_kwargs` and doing a single step puts me past the point args are expanded. Putting the same `set_trace` in each overridden function shows that none of them are called.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't mind that it's copying the contents of my container, I just want it *all* to get copied. ;)

Comment: The trouble is that you've inherited from `dict`, and `kwargs` is just taking a copy of the `dict` part of your class. (`kwargs` is `{'b':2}` in your test.) I don't know what the solution is, though.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I was worried it was from inheriting dict. I guess I'll rewrite to inherit collections.MutableMapping and see if that works. I guess the built-in dict gets expanded in C-land?

Comment: `dict(cm)` will also fail, I think.

Comment: I think `collections.MutableMapping` is the recommended way to do this anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating a keyword argument dictionary, the behavior is the same as passing your object into the `dict()` initializer, which results in the dict `{'b': 2}` for your `cm` object:

```
>>> cm = ChainableMap({'a': 1})
>>> cm['b'] = 2
>>> dict(cm)
{'b': 2}
```

A more detailed explanation of why this is the case is below, but the summary is that your mapping is converted to a Python dictionary in C code which does some optimization if the argument is itself another dict, by bypassing the Python function calls and inspecting the underlying C object directly.

There are a few ways to approach the solution for this, either make sure that the underlying dict contains everything you want, or stop inheriting from dict (which will require other changes as well, at the very least a `__setitem__` method).

**edit:** It sounds like [BrenBarn's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890066/making-custom-containers-work-with-kwargs-how-does-python-expand-the-args/11890526#comment15824502_11890066) to inherit from `collections.MutableMapping` instead of `dict` did the trick.

You could accomplish the first method pretty simply by just adding `self.update(parent)` to `ChainableMap.__init__()`, but I'm not sure if that will cause other side effects to the behavior of your class.

**Explanation of why `dict(cm)` gives `{'b': 2}`**:

Check out the following CPython code for the dict object:
http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Objects/dictobject.c#l1522

When `dict(cm)` is called (and when keyword arguments are unpacked), the `PyDict_Merge` function is called with `cm` as the `b` parameter.  Because ChainableMap inherits from dict, the if statement at line 1539 is entered:

```
if (PyDict_Check(b)) {
    other = (PyDictObject*)b;
    ...
```

From there on, items from `other` are added to the new dict that is being created by accessing the C object directly, which bypasses all of the methods that you overwrote.

This means that any items in a ChainableMap instance that are accessed through the `parent` attribute will not be added to the new dictionary created by `dict()` or keyword argument unpacking.

Comment: Unfortunately the other side effects wouldn't be acceptable for my use-case. I've changed to inheriting from `collections.MutableMapping` and that has fixed my problems.

Comment: @grncdr: Even when inheriting from `collections.MutableMapping`, you still should provide `__len__()`, which is missing from your example code.

Comment: @F.j: The keyword argument unpacking does not actually call `dict()` on the argument following `**`, but rather `PyDict_Update()` with a newly created dictionary and the mapping, but this call will also end up at `PyDictMerge()`, so it is essentially as you said.

Comment: @grncdr - Glad you found a clean solution, using `collections.MutableMapping` did not occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 this is still the most helpful question and answer I find for this topic, so adding followup here.

Inheriting from Mapping is not strictly needed. It just allows you to only fill in a few needed methods, and then the rest are derived using those building blocks. If you want the bare bones, according to the [cpython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7707b14489644073ab0153f5751c6ddbf3fc6f91/Objects/dictobject.c#L3685), the only two things required for kwarg unpacking to work are a `__getitem__(self, key: str)` and a `keys(self) -> Sequence[str]` method. Testing this out shows this works:

```py
class MyMap:
    def keys(self):
        return ["a", "b"]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key * 2


def f(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


f(**MyMap())
# {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb'}
```